# Правильно ли реализована функция получения списка товаров?

Tags: php, mysql, join, фильтры

Хотелось бы узнать, правильно ли я реализовал выборку товаров из базы?

Post::pSQL() - защита от  SQL инъекций

```
public static function products($shop_id = false,$category_id = false,$filters = false, $novinka = false, $start = false, $stop = false,$count = false, $sort = false,$products_id = false){

    // Если указан парметр $count, то функция вернет количество записей
    if($count == TRUE){
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'products pr';
    }else{
        $sql = 'SELECT pr.*,.shop.shop_url FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'products pr';
        $sql .= ' LEFT JOIN '.DB_PREFIX.'shops shop ON shop.id = pr.shop_id ';
    }
    // Используем ID фильтров (1,2,3,4), по ним есть вопрос, укажу его ниже..
    if($filters)
        $sql .= ' LEFT JOIN '.DB_PREFIX.'products_to_filters fp ON fp.product_id = pr.product_id ';

    // Если это frontend то показываем только активные товары
    if(self::$front)
        $where[] = 'pr.visible = 0';

    // На сайте магазинов несколько, поэтому присутствует и этот параметр
    if($shop_id){
        $where[] = 'pr.shop_id = '.(int)$shop_id;
    }

    // Это ID товаров, я его использую в поиске, так как сначала получаю список ID с товарами из sphinx, а потом уже делаю свой запрос.
    if($products_id){
        $products_id = Post::pSQL($products_id);
        $where[] = ' pr.product_id IN ('.$products_id.') ';
    }

    // Вывод товаров по категории (У товара может быть только одна категория)
    if($category_id){
        $category_id = Post::pSQL($category_id);
        $where[] = ' pr.category_id IN ('.$category_id.') ';
    }

    if($filters){
        $where[] = ' fp.filter_id IN('.$filters.')';
    }

    // Параметр, который говорит о том, что показывать этот товар на главной в блоке "НОВЫЕ ТОВАРЫ"
    if($novinka){
        $where[] = ' pr.special = 1 ';
    }

    // Продукт не должен быть удален (При удалении товара, проверяю есть ли он в заказах, если нет удаляю из базы, если есть, то оставляю с параметром del = 1)
    $where[] = ' pr.del != 1 ';

    // Превращаем массив с условиями в строку для SQL запроса
    if($where){
        $sql .= ' WHERE ';
        foreach($where as $item){
            $sql .= $item .' AND ';
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql,'AND ');
    }

    // Задаем ключ сортировки

    if(!$sort)
        $sort = 'sort DESC';

    // Если $sort была не передана, то $sort достанет из сессии, ну если она там есть соответственно.
    $sort = Tools::sortBy('products',$sort);

    if($count == false)
        $sql .= ' GROUP BY pr.product_id ORDER BY pr.'.$sort;

    // откуда до куда
    if($stop){
        $sql.= ' LIMIT ';
        if($start)
            $sql .= (int)$start.',';

        $sql .= (int)$stop;
    }

    //echo $sql;

    $res = Db::Instance()->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $res->execute();

    // Опять же если мы не считаем количество товаров, а должны получить массив, перебираем его для того чтобы, уже к тем товарам, которые будем отображать на странице, добавить картинки и установить цену (цена может быть по акции или просто указана old-price), а так же получаем атрибуты товара
    if($count == FALSE){
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $res->fetch()){
            // Тут в сам запрос углубляться смысла нет, в результате получаем массив с картинками
            $img = Db::Instance()->mySelect("products_images",'WHERE product_id = ? ORDER BY main DESC',array($row['product_id']));
            if($img['id']) {$row['images'][] = $img;}
            else {$row['images'] = $img;}

            $row = self::setNewProductPriceByDiscount($row);

            $row['attributes'] = self::arrayAttributes(self::getProductAttributes($row['product_id']));

            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }else{
        $rows = $res->fetch();
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Готов выслушать любую критику... так как хочется все таки научиться программировать грамотно

Вопрос по фильтрам: я так понял что реализация фильтров у меня неправильная, так как мне нужно сначала сгруппировать фильтры. Т.е.

```
Получить, что то такое:

    $arr[0]['title'] = 'Размер';
    $arr[0]['filters'] = array(2,5,6); // IDs фильтров с размерами

    $arr[1]['title'] = 'Вес';
    $arr[1]['filters'] = array(1,3,4);
```

Чтобы потом из них составить строку такого типа:

WHERE filters IN(2,5,6) AND filters IN (1,3,4)

Получить товары где, размер равен 2 ИЛИ 5 ИЛИ 6 **И** Вес равен 1 ИЛИ 3 ИЛИ 4 - ЭТО будет правильным условием для фильтрации товаров?

Comment: "**защита от SQL инъекций**" судя по всему - фигня на палочке это, а не защита. [Защита от SQL инъекций](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D1%82+sql+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Помимо всего прочего, по-моему лучше юзать какой-нибудь ORM вместо самостоятельного написания sql-запросов и манипулирования записями базы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое. Косяков здесь много, но самый смешной код - вот этот:

```
$res = Db::Instance()->pdo->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();
```

Код, который по идее призван защищать от инекций, на самом деле ни от чего не защищает. Поскольку все данные фигачатся прямо в запрос, обрабатываемые бессмысленной функцией `Post::pSQL()`, вместо того, чтобы передаваться в `execute()`.

Я соглашусь, что добавление данных в запрос через плейсхолдеры в PDO вызовет еще большее количество говнокода, но других вариантов у нас в принципе нету. Любые данные должны попадать в запрос только через плейсхолдеры.

Второе. Функция чудовищно раздута. Это просто эталон спагетти-говнокода.

Тебе надо обязательно написать для этого запроса квери-билдер.
чтобы каждое условие обрабатывалось своим собственным методом.
И тогда код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
$q = new productsQuery()
    ->addFilters($filters)
    ->addFront(self::$front)
    ->addShop($shop_id)
    // ...  и так далее
;
```

дальше мы дергаем желаемый метод получения результата

```
$q->getCount();
```

или

```
$q->getData();
```

кстати, если тебе count нужен только для постранички, то обрати внимание на такую фичу как `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Cами методы выглядят стандартно - есть переменная класса $where, и методы добавляют (или не добавляют) к ней условия:

```
public function addShop()
{
    if($shop_id)
    {
        $this->where[]       = 'pr.shop_id = :shop';
        $this->data['shop']  = $shop_id;
    }
    return $this; // allows metod-chaining
}
```

обрати внимание на переменную `$data`: это массив, в который ты должен собрать все переменные, которые пойдут в запрос. Чтобы потом передать его в execute.

Правда, с параметрами оператора LIMIT может быть косяк. Как его решить - читай тут: http://www.phpfaq.ru/pdo#limit

Таким образом ты получишь *рефакторинг* своего кода - т.е. приведение его в удобоваримый вид.

Да! по провду сборки WHERE из массива - открой для себя оператор `join()`, он же `implode()` ;)

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ!!!! За такой развернутый ответ, честно сказать не думал, что кто то будет разбираться в куче этого кода. Чтож, буду исправлять ошибки. Shorty если бы кинул мне примеры такого кода, было бы вообще шикарно. Готов заплатить 500р за ответ и примеры.

Comment: За SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS спасибище!!!!

Comment: Что то не очень любят SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.  http://php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26891